# Accessing associative array in twig

Tags: twig

I have this array:

```
$modules = array(
    'users',
    'submodule' => array(
        'submodule1',
        'submodule2',
    ),
);
```

My question is how can I access all the values and display it on html?

I have tried the following but no luck :

```
{% for key, module in modules  %}
        {% if modules.key is iterable %}
              {{ module }}
        {$ else %}
            {{ module }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array has only 2 levels, you can just do something close to what you did:

```
{% for module in modules %}
  {% if module is iterable %}
    {% for submodule in module %}
    <p>{{ submodule }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
  <p>{{ module }}</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Will give you (with the context you given):

```
<p>users</p>
<p>submodule1</p>
<p>submodule2</p>
```

See [fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/0au1nf)

---

But if your array has an arbitrary number of levels, you should do some recursive using macros:

```
{% macro show_array(array) %}

    {% from _self import show_array %}
    {% for module in array %}

        {% if module is iterable %}
            {{ show_array(module) }}
        {% else %}
            <p>{{ module }}</p>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import show_array %}
{{ show_array(modules) }}
```

With the following context (in YAML format):

```
modules:
  0: users
  submodule:
      0: submodule1
      1: submodule2
      subsubmodule:
        0: subsubmodule1
        1: subsubmodule2
```

This will give you:

```
<p>users</p>
<p>submodule1</p>
<p>submodule2</p>
<p>subsubmodule1</p>
<p>subsubmodule2</p>
```

See [fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/sf0oc8)